# WHILE loop to begin only when ELSEIF condition is true

Tags: if-statement, file-io, lua

I'm new to lua, and am trying to write some code to send information to a text file that is overwritten each loop cycle.The info sent to the text file is different based on a value that increases to a specific known number **(3 for this example)** and then decreases below that number in any order.

Here's where I am stuck:

> I want to send different info to the text file using the same values
>   but based on whether the value has reached 3 or not, if that makes
>   sense.

Example in English:

- if value is **2** and has not reached 3 then write: **UP 2**
- if value is **2** and has reached 3 then write: **DOWN 2**
- if value is **3** then write: **TOP**

My Question:

Can I get an *infinite while loop* to start inside **another** *infinite while loop* when a value meets a specific `elseif` condition. I want to try and use the loop structure below if possible.

My Code looks somewhat like this:

```
while true do
    file = assert(io.open("file.txt","w+"))
    value = ipc.readSD(0x0BE8)
       if value = 0
       file:write("UP 0")
       file:close()
       elseif value = 1
       file:write("UP 1")
       file:close()
       elseif value = 2
       file:write("UP 2")
       file:close()
       elseif value = 3
       file:write("TOP")
       file:close()
           --How do I trigger/start this inner loop?
           while true do
           --now stay in here until break
           file = assert(io.open("file.txt","w+"))
           value =  ipc.readSD(0x0BE8)
                  if
                        value = 0
                        file:write("DOWN 0")
                        file:close()
                        break
                  elseif
                        value = 1
                        file:write("DOWN 1")
                        file:close()
                  elseif
                        value = 2
                        file:write("DOWN 2")
                        file:close()
                  else
                        break
       else
       file:write("OUTSIDE")
       end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax errors in your code, it shouldn't compile at all.

- Use `==` to compare equal instead of `=`
- For every `if` / `elseif`, there should always be a corresponding
  `then`.
- For every `if` / `while` / `do` block, there should always be a
  corresponding `end`.

As for your question, if I understand it correctly, you can use `goto` to simulate `continue` when you don't want to enter the inner loop:

```
while true do
    value = getValue()
    if value == 1 then
        --not enter inner loop
        goto continue
    elseif value == 2 then
        --enter inner loop
    end
    while true do
        --inner loop
    end
    ::continue::
end
```